# create dynamic layout in fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, dynamic, view

i want create a dynamic layout in fragment. But when i trying to create dynamic buttons layout on Network response which is called in OnCreate(), but the view is not generating getting blank view.  In getComponents() contains NetworkResponse() and basis on response will create dynamic view as given below

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   getComponents();
}
private void getComponents(){
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                            ToggleButton toggleButton = new ToggleButton(getActivity());
                            toggleButton.setChecked(false);
                            toggleButton.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.toggle_selector));
                            ll.addView(toggleButton);
                            rootView = ll;
}
```

Comment: where do you create your view/ in which method?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should create your dynamic layout in [onCreateView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) instead of onCreate()

For example,

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle
            savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

        RelativeLayout fragment_container = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id
                .fragment_container);

        // Create a button 
        Button button = new Button(getContext());

        // add the button in fragment
        fragment_container.addView(button );

        return view;
    }
```

the fragment xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Briefly, you are adding any view on container of the fragment

Comment: on the basis of Network response say Api returns 4 buttons and that time i have to generate the 4 views

Answer (score 0):

Fragment cycle is different from Activity cycle in Android.
it has onCreate() where it creates fragment activity

onCreateView() here it creates and return view to its fragment activity. if you want to add dynamic view, it should be added here.

Then onViewCreated() here it notifies you after view successfully created and returns you its instance, now you can set Listeners and use setText getText and other view related attributes here.

Comment: u r right but my problem is different like if api retuns 3 or 4 views i have create the views on the basis api result and then have to return that view onCreateView()

Comment: Is your web call also in this fragment? Or you're fetching data from the previous screen?

Comment: fetching data in this fragment

Comment: Then you can't do it in onCreateView because your web call will be in onViewCreated and on you'll create dynamic views on the success of your webcall you can use getView() and change your frame layout with linear or relative layout, then you can add buttons.

RelativeLayout fragment_container = (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id
                .fragment_container);

        // Create a button 
        Button button = new Button(getContext());

        // add the button in fragment
        fragment_container.addView(button );